# Переполнение указателя

Tags: c++, указатели

Вот пример кода:

```
    int a[2] = {5, 10};
    int* b = a + 1;

    cout << a << endl;
    cout << b + 18446744073709551615UL << endl;
```

Вывод:

```
0x7ffd5a82dd30
0x7ffd5a82dd30
```

Отмечу, что константа в коде - это `2^64 - 1`. Как можно объяснить данное поведение? Происходят ли какие-то касты при вычислении этого выражения? Или происходит просто тупое переполнение указателя (который в 64битной системе в памяти имеет по сути такое же представление, как и UL)?

Comment: Так как при арифметике с указателями ты выходишь за пределы массива, то здесь чистое UB. См. [`[expr.add]`](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#4.3)

Comment: 1) Так как указатель `b + 18446744073709551615UL` не указывает ни на элемент массива `a`, ни на гипотетический элемент за последним элементом массива `a`, то поведение приведённого кода не определено. 2) Судя по всему в вашем случае действительно произошло обычное переполнение. В предположении, что типы `int *` и `unsigned long` имеют одинаковое представление, и тип `unsigned long` 64-битный, и тип `int` 4-байтовый, получим, что адрес `a` в байтах изменится так: `a + 4 + 4*(2^64 - 1) == a + 2^66 == a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда вы добавляете к указателю константу, к его фактическому значению прибавляется эта константа, помноженная на размер типа данных, на которые ссылается указатель. В данном случае константа `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` (шестнадцатиричное представление 18446744073709551615) умножается на 4 (размер типа `int`), т.е. сдвигается влево на два бита. Старшие два бита при этом теряются, и получается, что к адресу, который является значением указателя, прибавляется число `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFC` (18446744073709551612). Т.е., происходит *бесзнаковое переполнение*! Однако, если представить число `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFC` в *дополнительном коде* (т.е., вычтя его из 2^64), то получим его эквивалент в знаковой трактовке - `-4`. Т.е., добавляя к адресу число `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFC`, вы на деле вычитаете из него число `4`. А с точки зрения *арифметики указателей* языка Си, из указателя `b` у вас вычитается `1`, т.е. вы получаете значение `a`.

Именно выше описанное и происходит с вашим кодом в архитектуре x86/amd64. Именно по-этому вы получили такой результат. Но тут, как говорится, есть нюанс. В спецификации языка C/C++ вроде как ничего не написано про то, что всё так и должно быть (если я не прав, то пусть меня камрады поправят). А значит и гарантировать полученный результат для всех компиляторов нельзя (не говоря уже про другую архитектуру, в которой переполнение может обрабатываться процессором совершенно иначе). Короче, суть в том, что приведённый вами код в общем случае вызывает *неопределённое поведение*, UB. Это надо иметь ввиду.